# C code showing the error : *** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated Aborted (core dumped)

Tags: arrays, c, for-loop, function-definition, stack-smash

I have a program in C that split an array into two sub_arrays , it's perfectly giving results for even & odd array.length , but i have this error :

```
*** stack smashing detected ***: <unknown> terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

And this is the C code :

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define N 7

int arr[N] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};

void print(int *array, int start , int finish)
{
    for(int i = start ; i < finish ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
        if(i == finish - 1)
            printf("\n");
    }
}
void init(int *array, int start, int finish)
{
    for(int i = start ; i < finish ; i++)
        array[i] = arr[i];
}
int main()
{
    int left[N/2];
    int right[N/2];
    init(left,0,N/2);
    init(right,N/2,N);

    print(left,0,N/2);
    print(right,N/2,N);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Choose an odd value for `N` and then use `N/2` everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You declared an array of `3` elements

```
#define N 7

//...

int right[N/2];
```

But you are trying to access elements beyond the array within the function `init`

```
void init(int *array, int start, int finish)
{
    for(int i = start ; i < finish ; i++)
        array[i] = arr[i];
}
```

due to this call

```
init(right,N/2,N);
```

That is the valid range of indices for the array `right` is `[0, N / 2 )` but within the function you are using indices in the range `[N /2, N )`.

The same problem exists with the call of the function `print`

```
print(right,N/2,N);
```

The array `right` must be declared like

```
int right[N - N / 2];
```

And for example the function `init` should be defined like

```
void init( int *a1, size_t n, const int *a2 )
{
    for( size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        a1[i] = *a2++;
}
```

and called like

```
init( right, N - N / 2, arr + N / 2 );
```

In turn the function `print` can be defined like

```
void print( const int *a, size_t n )
{
    for( size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }

    putchar( '\n' );
}
```

and called like

```
print( right, N - N / 2 );
```

For the array `left` the function calls will look like

```
init( left, N / 2, arr );
```

and

```
print( left, N / 2 );
```

Comment: ahh okay , so what is the solution , should i put a condition to check if the array.length is an odd or even number then find the right start and finish ?

Comment: @bwass31 See my updated post.

Comment: `int right[N - N / 2];` // this is so smart , very nice ! please can you explain this block :`void init( int *a1, size_t n, const int *a2 )
{
    for( size_t i = 0 ; i < n ; i++)
        a1[i] = *a2++;
}`

Comment: @bwass31 the for loop is equivalent to for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; i++ ) a1[i] = a2[i];